# Apply calculation to a 2d array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have a 2d array and I want to do a calculation on each element in the array and then return the index which results in the smallest value.

I have tried iterating through each element in the 2d array and running the calculation. If the calculated result is smaller than the currently stored minimum I set that to the minimum.

This works but it runs so slowly it makes the solution a non starter. It performs each calculation quickly but because of the number of elements in the array the calculation for the whole array is stupidly long.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: How big is the array? Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Ill try and get something to post up.

Comment: I would avoid using a 2D array and use a flattened 1D array, where the first `N` elements are the first row, the second `N` elements the second row and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a flattened 1D array like this:

```
Public Class FlatMatrix
    Private m_elems As Double()
    Private m_rows, m_cols As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal rows As Integer, ByVal cols As Integer)
        Me.m_cols = cols
        Me.m_rows = rows
        Me.m_elems = New Double(Me.m_rows * Me.m_cols - 1) {}
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal other As Double(,))
        Me.m_cols = other.GetLength(0)
        Me.m_rows = other.GetLength(1)
        Me.m_elems = New Double(Me.m_rows * Me.m_cols - 1) {}

        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.m_rows - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To Me.m_cols - 1
                Me.m_elems(i * m_cols + j) = other(i, j)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
    Default Public Property Item(ByVal index As Long) As Double
        Get
            Return Me.m_elems(index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            Me.m_elems(index) = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Default Public Property Item(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal col As Integer) As Double
        Get
            Return Me.m_elems(Me.m_cols * row + col)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            Me.m_elems(Me.m_cols * row + col) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Que(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal col As Integer) As Long
        Return Me.m_cols * row + col
    End Function

    Public Sub DeQue(ByVal index As Long, ByRef row As Integer, ByRef col As Integer)
        col = index Mod m_cols
        row = index / m_cols
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property Size() As Long
        Get
            Return m_elems.LongLength
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property RowCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_rows
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ColumnCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_cols
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property InnerArray()
        Get
            Return m_elems
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

which is then called with some test code like:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Const N As Integer = 10000

    ' Initialize with random numbers
    Dim A As Double(,) = New Double(N, N) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To N - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To N - 1
            A(i, j) = 10 * rnd.NextDouble() - 5
        Next
    Next

    ' Measure finding min through all the elements
    Dim i_min As Integer = -1, j_min As Integer = -1
    Dim x_min As Double = Double.MaxValue
    sw.Start()
    For i As Integer = 0 To N - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To N - 1
            Dim x As Double = A(i, j)
            If x_min > x Then
                x_min = x
                i_min = i
                j_min = j
            End If
        Next
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    Dim t_A As Long = sw.ElapsedTicks
    Console.WriteLine("xmin={0} at ({1},{2})", x_min, i_min, j_min)

    ' Measure finding min thorugh flatten matrix
    sw.Reset()
    Dim B As New FlatMatrix(A)
    x_min = Double.MaxValue
    sw.Start()
    Dim vals As Double() = B.InnerArray
    For k As Long = 0 To N * N - 1
        'Dim x As Double = B(k) ' This is slower
        Dim x As Double = vals(k) ' This is faster
        If x_min > x Then
            x_min = x
            B.DeQue(k, i_min, j_min)
        End If
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    Dim t_B As Long = sw.ElapsedTicks
    Console.WriteLine("xmin={0} at ({1},{2})", x_min, i_min, j_min)
End Sub
```

and I get about a 25% reduction in time for a 10000x10000 matrix.